# Fetch record from table?

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I have table in which data is like this

**Mapping Relationship**

1 task_id is mapped to multiple task_detail_id (**1 to Many**)

```
Task_detail_id  Task_id    Creation_date
1                20         2020-05-02 20:28:23.354
2                21         2020-05-02 20:28:23.354
3                22         2020-05-02 19:28:23.354
4                22         2020-05-02 18:28:23.354
5                22         2020-05-02 17:28:23.354
6                22         2020-05-02 16:28:23.354
7                22         2020-05-02 15:28:23.354
8                23         2020-05-02 10:28:23.354
9                24         2020-05-02 09:28:23.354
10               24         2020-05-02 08:28:23.354
11               24         2020-05-02 07:28:23.354
```

What I want is to traverse the table and fetch record as if **same task_id exist more than 2 times then fetch top 2 (latest)** records for that task_id

Sample Output

```
Task_detail_id  Task_id         Creation_date
1                 20            2020-05-02 20:28:23.354
2                 21            2020-05-02 20:28:23.354
3                 22            2020-05-02 19:28:23.354
4                 22            2020-05-02 18:28:23.354
8                 23            2020-05-02 10:28:23.354
9                 24            2020-05-02 09:28:23.354
10                24            2020-05-02 08:28:23.354
```

Comment: Tag only the database that you use.

Comment: I am using Postgresql

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text, not images. ([mcve])

Comment: Did that please have a look

Comment: Why are the task_ids 20 and 21 in the output? They only exists once, not "more than 2 times".

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, I want all the record just filter out those task_detail_id which have same task_id count more than twice.

Comment: So you you meant "*fetch top 2 (latest) records for that **task_detail_id***"

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is typically done with a window function:

```
select task_detail_id, task_id, creation_date
from (
  select task_detail_id, task_id, creation_date, 
         row_number() over (partition by task_id order by creation_date desc) as rn
  from data
) t
where rn <= 2
order by task_detail_id, task_id;
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=0a138f4f4f69bb2b0a9fc9bb614323c6)

Comment: Above solution is returning all the rows. i:e It did not matched with sample output

Comment: @Sam: sorry, should have been `partition by task_id`